# How to install PhpMyAdmin having MySQL database/logins through FTP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I have MySQL database. I have FTP logins. I am trying to install PhpMyAdmin through FTP. I have already uploaded PhpMyAdmin folder from phpmyadmin.net to FTP, what should I do now to connect PhpMyAdmin to MySQL database? I can't find any config files where I have to insert host url, database name, username and password from MySQL database. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot connect to MySQL via FTP considering no **F** iles are being **T** ransferred via its **P** rotocol.

Comment: The author is asking how to set up all configuration using ftp only. I.e. how to create config file and upload it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, download phpmyadmin from their [website](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php). Next, unzip it to the preferred directory to the server using FTP, SSH, etc - anything you prefer. Find config.sample.inc.php file in the root directory of phpmyadmin, rename it to config.inc.php and edit necessary options.

Comment: just realized you uploaded files already. Still, I suggest using sample config file provided

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the config.inc.php file -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#quick_install shows you the format.